# Window 7 loading recovery options every time

Tags: windows-7, boot

After improper shutdown, windows 7 is opening "system recovery options" every time. I have tried booting through normal, safe, last known good configuration etc options. But nothing is working.

"start up repair" is not fixing the problem. restore is not supposed to work since I never make any restore point.

it is reporting that Windows/System is not found. It is not reporting/informing about any specific file.

Is this problem related to MBR?

I have windows 8 on another drive. Is there any way, I can fix windows 7 through logging in to windows 8?

Comment: I would try repairing the MBR, if its not of need of repair, performing a repair won't do any harm.

Comment: I tried it through EasyBSD. But it dint work. I again run startup repair, stopped it in between since it takes long time. logs are saying "registry is corrupt" :(

Comment: If it says the registry is corrupt then your MBR is fine but your registry is corrupt. If you don't have a restoration point there isn't a great deal you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 6-7 hours, I resolved the problem with very simple solution.

First I tried EasyBSD to repair MBR. But done something wrong and I become helpless to start my PC with any OS. I tried many other tools too which comes in Hiren boot cd.

Then I installed windows 8 first, which started showing 2 OS entries after boot screen. However it was not allowing me to enter in previously installed OS. Then I tried with windows 7 bootable DVD who repaired my OS.

I must have tried it very first. :(